# Javascript replace dynamic words in String using regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a string

`@lorem ipsium et magnium @valor repium estacy`

i want to replace
 `@lorem ipsium` with `<span>@lorem ipsium</span>` 
and `@valor repium` with `<span>@valor repium</span>`.

basically what i want to do is replace the two words after "@". note that the first word has no whitespace before it.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work `/(@\w+\s\w+)/g`:

```
'@lorem ipsium et magnium @valor repium estacy'.replace(/(@\w+\s\w+)/g, '<span>$1</span>')
```

https://regexper.com/#%2F(%40%5Cw%2B%5Cs%5Cw%2B)%2Fg